# mysql:5.7 docker allow access from all hosts and create DB

Tags: mysql, docker

I got a problem with mysql:5.7 with Docker. I know there are many questions about this but I just can't get this to work. 
I simply want to create a mysql:5.7 container with docker-compose with the following settings on STARTUP!!:

- Create user "root" with password "mypw"
- Allow access with root user from ALL hosts and containers
- Create a table named "mytable"

My yml:

```
db:
 build: "."
  command:
   - "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
  ports:
   - "3306:3306"
  environment:
   - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="mypw"
  volumes:
   - "./mysql/database:/var/lib/mysql"
```

What i tried:

- Dockerfile: COPY ./mysqld.cnf /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
- mysqld.cnf contains the line "bind-address = 0.0.0.0" at the end
- Add script to /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ with content "CREATE DATABASE mydb;"
- MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DATABASE variables (can't connect either)
- use skip-grant-tables in mysqld.cnf (errors)
- MYSQL_ROOT_HOST="%"

I just don't get why especially allow access from everywhere is so hard to do.
Can anyone please help with where to put what?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one more variable called `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST`. You need to set this variable to `%`.

So your `docker-compose.yaml` file will be:

```
$ cat docker-compose.yaml 
version: "3"

networks:
  net: {}

services:

  db:
    #    build: "."
    image: mysql:5.7
    command:
      - "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
    ports:
      - "3309:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypw
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
    # volumes:
    #  - "./mysql/database:/var/lib/mysql"
```

Then I am able to connect with command:

```
$ mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1 -pmypw -P3309
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4
Server version: 5.7.32 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

### Your issue

Your issue may be related to volume. Once your database is initialized with some credentials you have to stop container, remove data, then modify `docker-compose.yaml` and start your services again.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I always delete data. I tried it and i can not even connect from WITHIN the container. From host: Access denied for user 'root'@'172.19.0.1' (using password: YES) From inside the container:  Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Try to connect w/o password.