# Building mysql / mariadb database with scema in docker

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

Hi I am building a service in which I need a Mysql/MariaDB database. I have been googling different solutions and I got the db started with a database created thanks to a guide a was following (never found the link again unfortunately).

#### Problem

The problem I am having is that the tables are not being created. I added the sql-scema file to /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ (you can check it down in the docker file) but it doesnt seem to be executing it (I have tried with both copy and ADD commands).

#### Current output

This is my current console output from the container:
[![image][1]][1]

The database is created but the SOW TABLES; command returns Empty Set.

#### Desired output

Since this db is going to be a service differents scripts connect to (currently python), I need to be able to create the db and the sql schema (tables, triggers, etc...) so my team can work with same configuration.

#### Some of the solutions I have tried (I cant find all the links i have visited only a few)

[How to import a mysql dump file into a Docker mysql container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65585749/how-to-import-a-mysql-dump-file-into-a-docker-mysql-container)

[mysql:5.7 docker allow access from all hosts and create DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65816685/mysql5-7-docker-allow-access-from-all-hosts-and-create-db)

[Can't connect to mariadb outside of docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66735729/cant-connect-to-mariadb-outside-of-docker-container)

[Mariadb tables are deleted when use volume in docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66453816/mariadb-tables-are-deleted-when-use-volume-in-docker-compose)

### Project structure

The structure is pretty simple I am using the following docker-compose.yml

### Docker-compose

I still have to try if the MARIADB_ enviroment variables are necessary here.

```
version: '3'

services:

    db-mysql:
        #image: mysql/mysql-server:latest
        build: ./mysql-db
        restart: always
        container_name : db-music
        ports: 
            - '3306:3306'
        
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pwd
            MYSQL_DATABASE : audio_service
            MYSQL_USER : user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD : password

        environment:
            MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: pwd
            MARIADB_DATABASE : audio_service
            MARIADB_USER : user
            MARIADB_PASSWORD : password
        #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145370/how-can-i-initialize-a-mysql-database-with-schema-in-a-docker-container?rq=1
        expose:
            - '3306:3306'
        volumes:
          - type: bind
            source : E:\python-code\Rockstar\volume\mysql
            target : /var/lib/mysql

          #- type: bind
            #source : E:\python-code\Rockstar\mysql-db\sql_scripts\tables.sql
            #target : /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

networks:
    net:
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 212.172.1.0/30
    host:
        name: host
        external: true
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM mariadb:latest as builder


# That file does the DB initialization but also runs mysql daemon, by removing the last line it will only init
RUN ["sed", "-i", "s/exec \"$@\"/echo \"not running $@\"/", "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

# needed for intialization
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD = pwd
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE = audio_service
ENV MYSQL_USER = user
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD = password

COPY sql_scripts/tables.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

# Need to change the datadir to something else that /var/lib/mysql because the parent docker file defines it as a volume.
# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume :
#       Changing the volume from within the Dockerfile: If any build steps change the data within the volume after
#       it has been declared, those changes will be discarded.
RUN ["/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh", "mysqld", "--datadir", "/initialized-db", "--aria-log-dir-path", "/initialized-db"]

FROM mariadb:latest

# needed for intialization
ENV MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
ENV MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD = pwd
ENV MARIADB_DATABASE = audio_service
ENV MARIADB_USER = user
ENV MARIADB_PASSWORD = password

COPY --from=builder /initialized-db /var/lib/mysql

EXPOSE 3306
```

### SQL schema file

```
create database audio_service;
use audio_service;

CREATE TABLE audio
(
audio_id BINARY(16),
title TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
content MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (audio_id)
) COMMENT='this table stores sons';

DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `audio_before_insert` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `audio` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF new.audio_id IS NULL THEN
    SET new.audio_id = UUID_TO_BIN(UUID(), TRUE);
  END IF;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to build your own image since the official `mysql` / `mariadb` images are already well suited. You only need to run them with the following as explained in their [image documentations](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/mariadb/README.md):

- [environment variables](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/mariadb/README.md#environment-variables) to initialize an new database with a respective user on the first run
- a [volume at `/var/lib/mysql` to persist the data](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/mariadb/README.md#where-to-store-data)
- any initialization/sql scripts [mounted into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/mariadb/README.md#initializing-a-fresh-instance)

So storing your SQL* into a `schema.sql` file right next to the `docker-compose.yml` the following is enough to achieve what you want:

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: pwd
      MARIADB_DATABASE: audio_service
      MARIADB_USER: user
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      # persist data files into `datadir` volume managed by docker
      - datadir:/var/lib/mysql
      # bind-mount any sql files that should be run while initializing
      - ./schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql

volumes:
  datadir:
```

*note that you can remove the `CREATE DATABASE` and `USE` statements from your `schema.sql` since these will be automatically done by the init script for you anyway

---

There are two reasons that your own setup isn't working as expected:

1. the line `COPY --from=builder /initialized-db /var/lib/mysql` won't work as expected for the same reason you described in your comment a bit above it: `/var/lib/mysql` is a volume and thus no new files a stored in it in the build steps after it was defined.
2. you are bind-mounting `E:\python-code\Rockstar\volume\mysql` to `/var/lib/mysql` in your `docker-compose.yml`.
   But this will effectively override any contents of `/var/lib/mysql` of the image, i.e. although your own image built from your `Dockerfile` *does* include an initialized database this is overwritten by the contents of `E:\python-code\Rockstar\volume\mysql` when starting the service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @acran I will try this as soon as I can and I will mark this as a correct answer if so. Just one little thing I think I did not quiet understand is the second point you mention. You see when I executed docker-compose up It didn't create the tables, yet, If I created the table manually it would persist over time (due to the binding) I understand that the binding happens After the creation of the table? BTW if you think the question is well formulated please vote up.

Comment: In your `docker-compose.yml` you only mounted `/var/lib/mysql` into the container and the `init.sql` is commented out. Whenever the `mariadb` image is started it checks for existing database files in `/var/lib/mysql` and if that is empty it will be initialized according to the `MARIADB_*` variables you provided. This is why in your case an empty database was created and persisted but not initialized with your custom sql.